# How to get the ip address open spherical camera devices and check if connected or not?

Tags: ios, swift, ip-address, theta360

I am creating an app where I am using Open spherical camera API to communicate with the camera. I wanted to understand how to get the gateway IP address of the camera and check if the camera is connected with the iPhone.

In a more specific way, I wanted to know the connected wifi network's gateway IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a third-party library [FGRoute](https://github.com/Feghal/FGRoute) which provides a method to get the gateway IP address.

As for checking if camera is connected, you can follow these steps:

1. Connect to the camera's Wifi network
2. Check `FGRoute.getGatewayIP()` for a valid IP address
3. If IP address is valid then send a command to the camera and check it's response

If it fails at any stage then, ofcourse, the camera is not connected.

---

FYI:

[RICOH THETA API v2.1](https://developers.theta360.com/en/docs/v2.1/api_reference/) conforms to [Open Spherical Camera API Version 2.0](https://developers.google.com/streetview/open-spherical-camera/) by Google, and so you have many commands like [`camera.getLivePreview`](https://developers.google.com/streetview/open-spherical-camera/reference/camera/getlivepreview) that you can send to the camera and check it's response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me solving major problem in my app.

Comment: I think this answer will help future devlopers. There is no active support from theta community on stack overflow.